# No funciona ninguna de las funciones de sqlite en php

Tags: php, sqlite

cuando quiero usar cualquiera de las funciones de sqlite, siempre recibo errores de llamadas, ya he sacado los ; en php.ini e igual sigue pasando lo mismo, realmente nose que hacer... he probado con sqlite_open, sqlite_query, sqlite_fetch_array y varios mas. siempre el error es el mismo q mostrare a continuacion

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sqlite_fetch_array()"

Comment: Hola @Ultimatux, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esto es Stackoverflow en español así que, por favor, traduce tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias zeross, no me habia dado cuenta que estaba en español, ahi ya lo edite.

Comment: Saludos, podrias agregar el codigo que estas intentando para poder darte una mejore respuesta, edita tu pregunta => [edit]<= y agrega el codigo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos deberías usar  [SQLite3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) un ejemplo:

```
$db = new SQLite3('myBase.db');
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla");

while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
   ....
   ...
}
```

para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la respectiva documentación..!!

Comment: `try{
    /*** SQLite conexion  ***/
    $dbhandler = new Sqlite3('prueba.db');
    echo "Handle creado ......";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "Base de datos no ha sido enlazada correctamente ...";
    die( "Consultas cerradas !!! $error");
}`                                                                                                                                      Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sqlite3' not found in        sale este error ahora probando el codigo que me mostraste @diego avila

Comment: saludos revisa tu sintaxis tu tienes "new Sqlite3" cuando deberia ser "new SQLite3"

Comment: si, ahi lo arregle pero me dice exactamente el mismo error             Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQlite3' not found in

Comment: Fijate como tienes "SQlite3"...es "SQLite3"..es decir "SQL" el mayusculas el resto en minusculas..

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in ... realmente hubiera querido que todo mi problema sea un error de mayus pero fijate que sigue diciendome lo mismo...

Comment: me habia faltado activar el SQLite3.dll en php.ini . Ahora si pude conectar a la base de datos y probe usar la sentencia while que me dejaste mas arriba y ya conecta e imprime en pantalla, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.